# How does __doPostback creates a url on asp.net website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dopostback

Please take a look at the below URL - 
https://www.event-reg.biz/oem-Koelnmesse/OnlineExhListing

In the sort by dropdown, you can select "Exhibitor A to Z" and press search. 
After when the data appears, they have a javascript function for each link 
(`javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$grdExhList$ctl00$ctl04$lnkExhLink','')`)
that executes in the browser to create a unique URL.

For example 
`https://www.event-reg.biz/oem-Koelnmesse/OnlineExh?e=/v5urzZW/hm8SuWqRTOYlg==&p=https%3a%2f%2fwww.event-reg.biz%2foem-Koelnmesse%2fOnlineExhListing` 
this URL gets created for the above Javascript function call.

I have done research about __doPostBack function but that doesn't seem to help.
Any kind of help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/usage-of-dopostback-in-a-real-environment/

Comment: @jenishSakhiya what happened to your Phone number question? I had an answer for you b4 bed and woke up to find it deleted. Anyways on the source code of that `www.madlan.co.il` link you showed, just search for this text `"phone":` and you will see the numbers listed inside the page's code.

Comment: @VC.One I found the same thing, I don't know how did I miss that. It was so silly of me. Thanks for looking into it though. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence of events:

1. Link is clicked on the client side. It will invoke the
   `__doPostBack` method which will invoke a POST to the URL:
   "**https://www.event-reg.biz/oem-Koelnmesse/OnlineExhListing**" and
   passes the __EVENTTARGET with value:
   "ctl00$MainContent$grdExhList$ctl00$ctl04$lnkExhLink", one among the many key/values posted. 
   On receiving the request at the server side, server provides the below response back to the client:
   "1|#||4|157|pageRedirect||%2foem-Koelnmesse%2fOnlineExh.aspx%3fe%3d%2fv5urzZW%2fhm8SuWqRTOYlg%3d%3d%26p%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.event-reg.biz%252foem-Koelnmesse%252fOnlineExhListing|"
2. Client now invokes a GET request to the URL received in the previous POST response which is: "%2foem-Koelnmesse%2fOnlineExh.aspx%3fe%3d%2fv5urzZW%2fhm8SuWqRTOYlg%3d%3d%26p%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.event-reg.biz%252foem-Koelnmesse%252fOnlineExhListing" which can be URL decoded to: "**/oem-Koelnmesse/OnlineExh.aspx?e=/v5urzZW/hm8SuWqRTOYlg==&p=https%3a%2f%2fwww.event-reg.biz%2foem-Koelnmesse%2fOnlineExhListing**"
3. URL "/oem-Koelnmesse/OnlineExh.aspx?e=/v5urzZW/hm8SuWqRTOYlg==&p=https%3a%2f%2fwww.event-reg.biz%2foem-Koelnmesse%2fOnlineExhListing" does a redirect at the server to: **"/oem-Koelnmesse/OnlineExh?e=/v5urzZW/hm8SuWqRTOYlg==&p=https%3a%2f%2fwww.event-reg.biz%2foem-Koelnmesse%2fOnlineExhListing"**, which is the final URL that you would see in the browser.

You can easily see the flow by intercepting the traffic using fiddler and see it for yourself:
[image: Fiddler Screenshot]